# best solution for upload progress bar for shared server user

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have seen lots of solution, but what is the best stable solutin for no-administrator user who cant config server. i found some of these:

- using apc extension
- perl cgi instead of php
- flash based
- using js framework

im not sure i could use extension, not understand perl to control over the process, and totally not use flash in mywebsite because significant percentage of user have not flash. and im not want to use framework because of growing mywebsite size.

i think must be a better ajax | js | php portable solution.

Comment: google search: ajax upload progress bar = 161.000 results

Comment: Check Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158853/creating-a-file-progress-bar-in-php

Comment: framework are going to be global future, but now in my country 20k is very much. and if i use framework, i should use jquery,mootool,prototype in my link because only progress bar is not my headache and every framework are specialize in some field. also i think cross-browser headache are mostly in layout design rather than client-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have listed all possibilities I know of - however even the AJAX based uploads utilize some Flash in the process, as far as I know (e.g. [**Uploadify**](http://www.uploadify.com)).

If you ask me, go for Flash. Most users have it, and it's the least hassle to set up.

By the way, using a JavaScript framework is often a really good idea, independently from your question. The increase in project size is insignificant (20-100 kb) and those libraries need to be loaded only once. They do make a *lot* of things easier to do, and offer a cross-browser consistent foundation for your user interface. If you use a lot of Javascript, you're almost always better off with a Framework.