# How to display progress loading image on file upload in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, progress-bar, loading

How to display simple progress loading image on file upload in PHP? without the use of APC

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a custom upload progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067802/creating-a-custom-upload-progress-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org).

For more detail check e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078339/best-solution-for-upload-progress-bar-for-shared-server-user) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158853/creating-a-file-progress-bar-in-php)